# I have Twilio and Firebase cloud messaging React-Native library use the same <intent-filter> MESSAGING_EVENT action in my AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, intentfilter

My problem is I have Twilio and Firebase cloud messaging React-Native library use the same  MESSAGING_EVENT action in my AndroidManifest.xml file. When my apps is running will only randomly run one service.

```
        <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.hoxfon.react.RNTwilioVoice.fcm.VoiceFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I want the apps can run both services in AndroidManifest.xml not only run one instead.